# Practical use of fork join_none

Tags: system-verilog

My question is about the `fork`...`join_none` construct in SV.

According to the [LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) section 9.3.2 *Parallel blocks*, Table 9-1—*fork-join control options*:

> The parent process continues to execute concurrently with all the processes spawned by the fork. The spawned processes do not start executing until the parent thread executes a blocking statement.

Using the `join_none` doesn't wait for any of the forked process to complete and proceeds executing the non-blocking statements. I am trying to think of a scenario where one would  use `join_none` during design/verification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common use of `fork/join_none` in SystemVerilog is when you want to spawn a dynamic number of parallel threads. In a testbench, each thread could represent a single device on a bus.

```
initial
  begin 
    N = $urandom_range(1,10);
    for( int j = 1; j <= N; ++j )
      fork
         automatic int k = j; // local copy, k, for each value of j
         start_a_thread(k);
      join_none
   end
```

Answer (score 2):

`join_none` is widely used in verification methodologies, such as [UVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Verification_Methodology).  It is used to spawn off multiple threads in parallel in the testbench.  For example, it can be used to start an interrupt monitor in parallel with a data bus driver.